# Spark Cassandra Connector: SQLContext.read + SQLContext.write vs. manual parsing and inserting (JSON -> Cassandra)

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

Good morning,

i just started investigating Apache Spark and Apache Cassandra. First step is a real simple use-case: taking a file containing e.g. customer + score.

Cassandra table has customer as PrimaryKey. Cassandra is just running locally (so no cluster at all!).

So the SparkJob (Standalone local[2]) is parsing the JSON file and then writing the whole stuff into Cassandra.

First solution was

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Application").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val cass = CassandraConnector(conf)

val customerScores = sc.textFile(file).cache()

val customerScoreRDD = customerScores.mapPartitions(lines => {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  lines
    .map(line => {
      mapper.readValue(line, classOf[CustomerScore])
    })
    //Filter corrupt ones: empty values
    .filter(customerScore => customerScore.customer != null && customerScore.score != null)
})


customerScoreRDD.foreachPartition(rows => cass.withSessionDo(session => {
  val statement: PreparedStatement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO playground.customer_score (customer,score) VALUES (:customer,:score)")
  rows.foreach(row => {
    session.executeAsync(statement.bind(row.customer.asInstanceOf[Object], row.score))
  })
}))

sc.stop()
```

means doing everything manually, parsing the lines and then inserting into Cassandra.

This roughly takes about *714020 ms* in total for 10000000 records (incl. creating SparkContext and so on ...).

Then i read about the spark-cassandra-connector and did the following:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Application").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
var sql = new SQLContext(sc)

val customerScores = sql.read.json(file)

val customerScoresCorrected = customerScores
  //Filter corrupt ones: empty values
  .filter("customer is not null and score is not null")
  //Filter corrupt ones: invalid properties
  .select("customer", "score")

customerScoresCorrected.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .options(Map("keyspace" -> "playground", "table" -> "customer_score"))
  .save()

sc.stop()
```

So much simpler in sense of needed code and using given API.

This solution roughly takes *1232871 ms* for 10000000 records (again all in all, so same measure points).

(Had a third solution as well, parsing manually plus using `saveToCassandra` which takes *1530877 ms*)

***Now my question:***

Which way is the "correct" way to fulfil this usecase, so which one is the "best practice" (and in a real scenario, clustered cassandra and spark, the most performing one) nowadays?
Cause from my results i would use the "manual" stuff instead of `SQLContext.read` + `SQLContext.write`.

Thanks for your comments and hints in advance.

Comment: We have had good results using the Cassandra connector when writing RDDs (using `saveToCassandra`). Using RDDs instead of DataFrames gives you the possibility to repartition according to Cassandra token ranges (using `repartitionByCassandraReplica`) which will result in most writes being local avoiding lots of Cassandra coordinator work.

Comment: Thanks @LiMuBei, this actually reduces `saveToCassandra` a little, even in local testcase. 
In total it still seems that "manual" solution (first code snippet) is still the fastest one.

Comment: Could it be that in your first solution you do not wait for your async operations to actually complete? It seems to me that this way might not guarantee that all insert operations finished successfully.

Comment: Huh ... you're right in my example i do not know if everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually after playing around now a long time, following has to be considered.

- Of course amount of data
- Type of your data: especially variety of partition keys (each one different vs. lots of duplicates)
- The environment: Spark Executors, Cassandra Nodes, Replication ...

For my UseCase playing around with

```
def initSparkContext: SparkContext = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Application").setMaster("local[2]")
        // since we have nearly totally different PartitionKeys, default: 1000
        .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.buffer.size", "1")
        // write as much concurrently, default: 5
       .set("spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes", "1024")
       // batch same replica, default: partition
       .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key", "replica_set") 
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc
}
```

did boost speed dramatically in my local run.

So there is very much need to try out the various parameters to get YOUR best way. At least that is the conclusion i got.